# I am attempting to append a list

Tags: append

person = ["Jack"]
for person in person ("Jack"):
    person.append(Straw)
print(person)

I keep getting the message list object is not callable and seem to be stuck on what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you are usign Python, let me format your code a bit for better readability:

```
person = ["Jack"]

for person in person("Jack"):
    person.append("Straw")

print(person)
```

If you just have a person list and you want to append something to it you don't need to loop over it, you just use the append method on lists (more info about this method [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). So the code should look like this:

```
person = ["Jack"]
person.append("Straw")
print(person)
```

Besides that you don't need to loop over the person list let me clarify another error I see in your code when looping over it:

```
persons = ["Jack", "Ryan", "Straw"]

for person in persons:
    print(person)
```

*Note1:* See that I renamed the list with the people name into a plural variable (also can be called `people`)

*Note2:* For looping over the list I just use the `persons` list name, and I don't access it with (`person("Straw")`), that way of accesing a list in Python does not exist and there is where the Python error comes in your console.